# TextMeshPro showing logo not text. Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, text

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9TQA.png)[image]

I'm stuck on this and a noobie to unity. So, in the text mesh pro is showing the logo not my text for the score counter I've made.

I wanted the ui text to display, my text that I typed not the componetes logo. I need this text to show so I could text my method.
-sorry for the the draw out repetive text I need to reach the text limit.

Comment: include a screenshot of your Hierarchy window & the inspector

Comment: Please give us more information like your component settings from the Inspector window like @DevAm00 suggests. Also the logo, I think will always appear because it's just an indicator that you have a TextMeshPro element on your screen. Probably you don't see the text that you enter, because of your text size. Try to decrease the size manually or select the auto-size option.

Comment: @NoraPī You have added the Canvas inspector. Can you please add the TextMeshPro object inspector?